# Convert to Enum

Tags: .net, entity-framework, enums, entity-framework-5

I just got Visual-Studio 2012 Professional and am using the Entity-Framework (5.0) designer.  I've been trying to convert a property to an Enum, and according to [this Microsoft video](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj248772.aspx) I right click the property and choose `Convert to Enum` at (2:06) - there is no option for converting in my context menu.

Here I'm trying to convert Role to Enum.  I've set Role to be an Int32.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following the video in the post closely, I opened the `Model Browser` to add an Enum manually.  After I had done so, and set the Role to the enum I had created.  To test if I could now `Convert To Enum` on the property, I changed the type back to Int32 and then right clicked the property and and low and behold I see the `Convert To Enum` option in the context menu!

So, if your having problems these are the steps I used to enable the `Convert To Enum` option.  This is a hack in my opinion, as now I cannot reproduce this behavior with a new solution and project.  Apparently once the Model Browser has been opened for the first time (or the complete steps below) it now shows the `Convert To Enum` option.

-1. Using the Quick Launch search window, I typed in `Model Browser` and opened it up.

[image: Model Browser search]

-2. Choose `Add New Enum Type...` from right clicking `Enum Types` in the Model Browser for your Data Model.

[image]

-3. Set your property to the enum, scroll to the bottom of the listed types in the combo-box and choose the enum.

Comment: This is weird, I don't see the `Enum Types` folder in my Model Browser.

Comment: @asattar Please note that Enum Types Folder olny appears if you target the .Net Framework 4.5

Answer (score 4):

i had this problem too!! i changed entity framework from 4 to 4.5 and problem solved! ;)

Answer (score 3):

When I had the same problem the solution was to set Target Framework to ".NET Framework 4.5".

Answer (score 0):

What was the type of the property before when you tried to convert it to an enum property? Convert to Enum option is only available when the type of the property is one of the types that can be the enum underlying type - Edm.Byte, Edm.SByte, Edm.Int16, Edm.Int32 or Edm.Int64. If the property type is not one of these types you cannot convert it to enum directly because the designer would not know what the underlying type should be and what's more important whether it would work with your database.

Comment: If you notice, I posted that it was an Int32.

Comment: I must have missed it. Do you have steps to repro this consistently (or a project I could open to see this and investigate)?

Comment: In my answer I said I couldn't reproduce it after I 'fixed' it.  The only option I can think is to reinstall VS2012 and add new project C# Lightswitch, then add C# class library, add ADO.Net Entity item, right click add Entity (not using toolbox and don't click Model Browser), then add a property, set its type to int32 and then try to right click convert to enum.  That is what I did to start with in short, though I added several other entities and some associations first before trying to create the enum.